# Disable SPACE BAR and ENTER keys in JOPTIONPANE

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

First, I apologize for the double post ( I can't delete my old one)...
Actually, I thought my problem was solved, but it's not...

I have a problem with my software developped in Java. The user (who would be a child of 7-9 years)  has to write a text in a JtextPane. When there's no time left for him to write, a pop-up appears saying "there's no time left, it's time to write another story".

The only problem is : if the user is writting when the message pops up, the pop-up disappears because the space bar or "enter" validates the message.
And when you write a text, you often press that keys... :/

Is there's anyway I can disable this fonction ? And allow the message to disappear only if the user click "OK" ?
I tried using listeners but It didn't work.

I used this to create the MessageDialog :

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                new UTIL_LireFichierTXT().getText(MessageTempsImparti)
                ,new UTIL_LireFichierTXT().getText(MessageAttention),JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
```

I am a trainee and my boss told me "you must show a pop-up", so I can't do anyway else...
Have you any idea to help me ? 
Thanks for reading.

Comment: Duplicated original has no answer and this one has.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a good idea, to do what you want, but I have a solution. You can simply disable all key events when dialog shown. Here is a sample.

```
    AWTEventListener myListener = new AWTEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
            if (event instanceof KeyEvent) {
                ((KeyEvent) event).consume();
            }
        }
    };
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(myListener, AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have a message!");
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().removeAWTEventListener(myListener);
```

Please use this solution only if your boss really want it. I would preffer to make your text component non-editable and show the warning message as ovelay to it (you can use JLayeredPane for this purpose).

Comment: THANK YOU SO, SO SO MUCH !! I know it's not the best way to solve my problem and I shouldn't use a pop-up for this application, but my boss really want it, and it works perfectly, just as I wanted. You saved me x) !! thanks again.

Comment: This is a good idea, better than rewrite showMessageDialog function.